# Mouse leaving the browser function does not work

Tags: javascript, function

I am creating a javascript trigger for my pop-up with Google tag manager. I have two conditions: one is that customer is exiting the browser and another on is that visitor has been on the site for 3 seconds.
For some reason, my variables don't turn to true but when I use alerts instead, it works fine. 
Could someone help me, please?

```
    var visitorLeave = false;
 var visitorInterested = false;
  function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}
addEvent(window,"load",function(e) {
    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
        if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
          var visitorLeave = true;
        }
    });
});
setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
function myFunction(){
   var visitorInterested = true;
};
if(visitorLeave === true && visitorInterested === true){
  alert("trigger me!");
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove "var " from before visitorLeave and visitorInterested inside your callback functions? You already declared them once in the top. Might be that the javascript compiler you use creates new variables locally (although that should only be the case if you used 'let' instead of 'var').

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't fix the problem. In console, if I check the variables, they remain false. But when I replace boolean with alert() it gives me an alert as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `var` in front of all but the first appearance of the variables `visitorLeave` and `visitorInterested` solves the issue. I could reproduce the problem with your original code.

Working code:

```
   var visitorLeave = false;
 var visitorInterested = false;
  function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}
addEvent(window,"load",function(e) {
    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
        if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
           visitorLeave = true;
            if(visitorLeave === true && visitorInterested === true){
              alert("trigger me!");
            }
        }
    });
});
setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
function myFunction(){
    visitorInterested = true;
};
```